# Unable to access map field value in jquery

Tags: jquery, openstreetmap, drupal-8

I have a form in Drupal 8 that has this map field:
[image]

When I select a place, latitude and longitude are shown in the fields below but fields values are not updated:

[image]

And when I check values like `console.log($('#edit-field-camp-localizacion-0-lat').val());`, I get nothing.

Anyway, if I check field in depth like `console.log($('#edit-field-camp-localizacion-0-lat'));`, I can see the value in there:

[image]

So the question is: any idea on how can I get the value from a .js file?

Comment: From the output, the value you have highlighted is: `$('#edit-field-camp-localizacion-0-lat')[0].value`

Comment: Yes but I call `console.log($('#edit-field-camp-localizacion-0-lat')[0].value);` and I got nothing.